# richTextBox1.Text = text with hyperlink

Tags: c#

I just learning c#
can you help me?
I trying this ->
 richTextBox1.Text = "https://www.google.com";
I actually see this text and it's clickable, but when I click on it nothing happens.
How I add the event to this link so it's will open a link?.

Also, how can I convert this link like present text "Google" and inside event to open  "https://www.google.com";

I know how to do Process.Start but I don't know how to insert this to richTextBox.

Comment: Does the rich text box use HTML?  Are you just asking how to make an HTML link?  Something else?  What on Earth does `Process.Start` have to do with this?

Comment: You better start from here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, then continue by fixing your questions' subject to represent a real question, and then fix the question itself. Ideally showing a concise piece of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or simply :

go to richTextBox Properties, set the DetectUrls property to true

then in the LinkClicked event :

```
private void richTextBox1_LinkClicked (object sender, LinkClickedEventArgs e) {
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(e.LinkText);
}
```